# When ever Update Manager does an update, my appearance settings change

Tags: 11.04

Using 11.04. When ever Update Manger does updates (have done 2 since install), when I log back in the Appearance Setting change from the default Ambiance settings to Radiance. I have to manually change back to Ambiance, log out, log back in for it to keep the settings.

Is Ambiance the default setting for 11.04?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the default setting but it should not change your own theme unless some part of it is either broken or deprecated.